# Changing scenes in unity using android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I wrote simple game in Unity, but menu on android is quite laggy. I was thinking to create native android application with levels in game to choose and use it to change scenes in unity. Is this is possible? 
There is some simple way to change scene in unity app using android app?